# Как сменить страницу ошибки :( Oops Internal Server Error 500 в .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

[image: 500 error]

Иногда вылетает при работе Asp Net проекта на .Net Core.
Нигде не нашел где её изменить.
Хочу заменить на свою страницу.
Страница ошибки не указывается в проекте, в IIS так же не смог её найти.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940362/how-change-default-oops-internal-server-error-500-%D0%B2-net-core

Answer (score 0):

В MSDN эта тема [неплохо описана](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling). Если вкратце - в методе `Configure` есть строчка:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();
    env.EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Production;
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    }
}
```

Данный блок указывает, что в env=Development - будет стек трейс и лог ошибки, в противном случае - будет вызываться `/Home/Error`. Если нужны статус коды, то следует почитать про `app.UseStatusCodePages();`, который позволяет установить свой собственный роутинг для кастомных ошибок. К примеру, так:

`app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");`